# Charts flickering

Tags: chart.js

How can I identify why is this charts.js flickering?

[image]

[image]

Comment: We can't see a flicker on a still picture. What do you mean? Could literally be anything. chart.js is a complex script. Have you changed the way it uses the canvas at all? Are there any javascript errors on the page?

Comment: @JayMee the tooltip is not rendering correct. There are no errors at console. The script is working fine, but there is flickering when the chart is rendering (animating) and the tooltip is with strange background behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark with the limited information.

A resize of the chart or window or the parent element (e.g. could be caused by a collapsing parent or sibling of the parent) will cause chartjs to trigger its resize event, redrawing the chart.

If you have animation turned off, this may not be noticeable unless you hover over a tooltip. Try turning animation on to see if the chart is redrawing.

Comment: Almost perfect. I defined parent's width and height abd worked like a charm. There was no need to change animation settings. Thanks!